# Grails using uuid id generator: Not very random

Tags: hibernate, uuid, grails-4

A simple Grails 4 app uses the `uuid` id generator with the Hibernate 7.0.4 plugin and PostgreSQL 10 under Ubuntu 20.04. Here is some output after 4 instances have been created:

```
=> select id,ttag,name from msg_template;
                id                | ttag |      name       
----------------------------------+------+-----------------
 ff808181781632030178163215190000 | publ | Notice01
 ff8081817816320301781632151f0001 | publ | Notice02
 ff808181781632030178163215230002 | publ | Signing01
 ff8081817816320301781635161b0003 | acme | Some thingy!
```

My assumption was uuid = randomness, but this result is very un-random. Is randomness not to be expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUIDs come in different versions and variants, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier. Not every version generates random values.

However, version 4 generates random values based on a random number generator.

For Java, the random number generator can be defined more precisely via the system property *java.security.egd*, see https://www.baeldung.com/java-security-egd.

With *java.util.UUID.randomUUID()* you generate UUIDs of version 4.

For Hibernate there are different ways to use UUID, here

- https://thorben-janssen.com/generate-uuids-primary-keys-hibernate/
- https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers/

can help.